# SQL/VBA INSERT issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I'm trying to create a user list depending on who uses my excel spreadsheet.

The idea being when the user opens the workbook, the open script downloads the user list, checks to see if that user exists and if not adds them to it.

Now I can download the user details with a stored procedure, but as soon as I add a line into it to check if the user exists, and if not add the user, VBA throws an error claiming 'Operation is not allowed when object is closed'

VBA code:

```
Sub UserDL()
Dim us As Worksheet
Dim USArr(0 To 11) As Variant
Dim sKey As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With UserList
    .RemoveAll
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
End With

ThisUser = Environ("userdomain") & "\" & Environ("username")

Call ConnecttoDB

Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With Cmd
    .CommandTimeout = 30
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = "CSLL.DLUsers"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters("@Alias").Value = Environ("userdomain") & "\" & Environ("username")

    Set rs = .Execute
End With

With rs     
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        While (Not .EOF)
            On Error Resume Next
            If (IsNull(rs("FirstName")) Or IsNull(rs("LastName"))) = True Then
                Call AliasDet(rs("Alias"))
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            For i = 1 To 11
                USArr(i - 1) = rs(i)
            Next i
                With UserList
                    sKey = rs("Alias")
                    If Not .Exists(sKey) Then
                        .Add sKey, USArr
                    End If
                End With
            .MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
End With

Set Cmd = Nothing: Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

SQL Stored Procedure:

```
    @Alias as varchar(max)
AS

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [CSLL].[Users] WHERE [Alias] = @Alias) INSERT INTO [CSLL].[Users] ([Alias], [Country], [Role]) VALUES (@Alias, 'UK', 'Employee')

SELECT * FROM [CSLL].[Users]
```

Can anyone help as to why it throws the error when the user doesn't exist (if the user does exist it runs fine so I expect it is to do with the SQL stored procedure but cannot see where)

Comment: There is nothing in your sql that seems out of place. Of course I can't see the table so I don't know if those columns exist or not. Do you really need varchar(max)? And I would recommend not using sql reserved word for naming your objects and column names. I would fire up profiler and see if your proc is even executing when the user does not exist.

Comment: I've double checked and triple checked - All the columns exist (fairly new at SQL didn't realise Alias was a reserved word). This table works fine with other stored procedures, and both the IF statement and the select statement work fine on there own. It is when they're combined and the if statement is true that it fails. Also running this as a query inside MSSMS works perfectly and returns the full table (as expected) it just doesn't seem to want to populate the recordset in vba if the user doesn't exist. if the user does exist it then does populate the recordset :S

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the `INSERT` statement attempting to return a value from the stored procedure. Try putting `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the top of your stored procedure to prevent the impacted record count from being returned:

```
[SP Header and Parameters]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON; -- Prevent insert from returning a result.

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [CSLL].[Users] WHERE [Alias] = @Alias)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [CSLL].[Users] ([Alias], [Country], [Role]) VALUES (@Alias, 'UK', 'Employee');
END

SELECT * FROM [CSLL].[Users]
```